# Move Linux Files so that they acquire owner and permissions of target folder

Tags: linux, filesystems

The immense responsibility of having to manually manage every possible detail of every operation when all circumstances require different techniques is really getting me down.

So there must be techniques that optimize some of these impossible chains of repetitive motions and strategies. Maybe a little 'self-healing' operations? I mean, I'm not expecting Bill Gates style managed states, but just some file and folder feature ops...

Like this one: can I expect to be able to move files into a folder with copy or scp and have the existing ownership and permissions of the source file be changed to the owner and permission of the target directory without having to do octal math and manual lookups to establish what the original folder permissions are?
Thanks

Comment: `copy` is not an universally known Unix command. Have you meant `cp` ? Also, the phrase "move files  with copy" sounds very confused. That is not a nitpick: it matters for your problem. Changing the owner of an existing file is not something a regular user can do at all.

Comment: @Stato Machino yes for sure it is possible to write a function to do it. But there are some points consider. please provide a sample src directory the file and target directory. for example if a directory have executable permission so that you want the target file have same? ownership can only be changed with `root` or `sudo`. so please clarify.

Comment: @q.undertow - 'copy' is a universally understood concept that is likely understood in nearly any context. Without any categorization to limit it to a domain, it should be recognizable by most people who have completed their first six years of schooling. And, if you asked someone to 'copy that file on the command line' most would choose to use cp. Pointing out such ambiguities based on personal perspectives on linguistic precision is a distraction. You simply introduce a no-op communication cycle in which you are requesting the author succumb you your standard. Just start with a likely meaning.

Comment: @binarysta - I appreciate your response. While ignoring os-orientations, windows does something like this when you move a file into a directory pre-configured with owner and permission settings. Those can be altered or 'coalesced' using tools available in the file management dialogs available to users in the right-click menus in the file manager.